# Not able to post the photo using jax rs api in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, jax-rs

Below is the code from the controller class
Its a method from controller class which has 2 methods for posting the photo and getting the photo. Unable to do mapping with this method it uses ajax API call
I guess the issue is with ajax api which is unable to map with this method,
I am not sure what's wrong here

```
    @Path("/{id}/photo")
     @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
       public Response updatePhoto(@PathParam("id") String id, @FormDataParam("photo") InputStream is) throws RecordNotFoundException {


            boolean updated = sanService.updatePhoto(id, is);
            if (updated)
                return Response.status(Status.OK).entity("").build();
            else
                return Response.status(Status.NOT_MODIFIED).entity("").build();
        }


    @GET
    @Path("/{id}/photo")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response getPhoto(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        String result = sanService.getPhoto(id);

        if (result == null)
            return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("").build();
        else {
            File file = new File(result);
            ResponseBuilder response = Response.status(Status.OK).entity((Object) file);
            response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + id + ".png");
            return response.build();
        }

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

        String uploadedFileLocation = "C://"
                + fileDetail.getFileName();


        writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

        String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }


    private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            String uploadedFileLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    uploadedFileLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Below is the error i am receiving in postman when i am hitting the path to post the photo

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-04-03T17:10:10.105+0000",
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/5cedvcb6rfsss5ff300eb/photo"
}
```

Comment: _"Unable to do mapping with this method"_ - What does this mean?

Comment: Please try to make your question a little more focused on one piece of code. You have a problem posting a file. Let's get down to _one_ method where you are trying to accept a file. Save the file somewhere. Check to see if it's saved. Then move on from there, Your question is confusing as it have so many different methods. Also It is not clear where the error is coming from; What resource you are trying to call.

Comment: I am using ajax api to call and I figured out ajax is not able to do mapping

Comment: I edited the question please check